# Fstream is draining the life out of me

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I have a code writing assignment for my computer class and it includes fstream classes. I have to write a code that manages and stores user data.
I had a hard time understanding this concept in class and C++ text books just want to keep showing me IPO charts not codes.
I would appreciate if someone can help me with my code and how I can store the users input data to be viewed later on notepad.
thank you in advance for all the help, I have been searching for days and could not figure it out.

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXLASTNAME = 20;
const int MAXFIRSTNAME = 10;
const int MAXPLAYERS = 20;

struct Baseball {
 char FirstName[MAXFIRSTNAME+1];
 char LastName[MAXLASTNAME+1];
 float AB;
 float singles;
 float doubles;
 float triples;
 float HR;
 float walks;
 double BA;
 double SA;
 double OBA;
};

int getData(Baseball[]);
void showData(Baseball[], int);

int main()
{
 Baseball stats[MAXPLAYERS];

 int players = getData(stats);
 showData(stats, players);

}
//function: int getData
//description: get the data for all the players the user wishes to input
//input: numerical data for averages and char for name of player
//output: none
int getData(Baseball stats[])
{
 int i, players;

 cout << "How many aquasocks players would you like to enter data for(1-20): ";
 cin >> players;
 cout << endl;



 for(i=0;i<players;i++) {
  cout << "Please enter aquasock #" << i+1 << "'s first name: ";
  cin >> stats[i].FirstName;

  cout << "Please enter aquasock #" << i+1 << "'s last name: ";
  cin >> stats[i].LastName;

  cout << "Please enter the number of at bats for player #" << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> stats[i].AB;

  cout << "Please enter the number of singles for player #" << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> stats[i].singles;

  cout << "Please enter the number of doubles for player #" << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> stats[i].doubles;

  cout << "Please enter the number of triples for player #" << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> stats[i].triples;

  cout << "Please enter the number of home runs for player #" << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> stats[i].HR;

  cout << "Please enter the number of walks for player #" << i+1 << ": ";
  cin >> stats[i].walks;
 }


 double sum = 0;

 for(i=0; i<players; i++) {
     sum += (stats[i].singles + stats[i].doubles + stats[i].triples + stats[i].HR);

  cout.precision(3);
  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  stats[i].BA = sum / (stats[i].AB);
  stats[i].SA = (stats[i].singles + (2*stats[i].doubles) + (3*stats[i].triples) + (4*stats[i].HR)) / (stats[i].AB);
  stats[i].OBA = (sum + stats[i].walks) / (stats[i].AB + stats[i].walks);
 }

    return players;
}
//function: void showData
//description: uses the data from function int getData to make a calculated chart of the players statistics.
//input: none
//output: chart of the users inputed data from function int getData
void showData(Baseball stats[], int players)
{
 int i;
 cout << endl << endl;
 cout << "lets see how this aquasock stats stack up!\n\n";


 cout << "First Name" << setw(14) << "Last Name" << setw(6) << "AB" << setw(6) << "1B" << setw(6) << "2B";
 cout << setw(6) << "3B" << setw(6) << "HR" << setw(6) << "BB" << setw(6) << "BA" << setw(6) << "SA";
 cout << setw(6) << "OBA" << "\n";


 cout << "----------" << setw(14) << "---------" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--";
 cout << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--";
 cout << setw(6) << "---" << "\n";


 for(i=0; i<players; i++)
 {
  cout << stats[i].FirstName
       << setw(15) << stats[i].LastName
       << setw(8) << stats[i].AB
       << setw(8) << stats[i].singles
       << setw(8) << stats[i].doubles
       << setw(8) << stats[i].triples
       << setw(8) << stats[i].HR
       << setw(8) << stats[i].walks
    << setw(8) << stats[i].BA
    << setw(8) << stats[i].SA
    << setw(8) << stats[i].OBA
       << endl;
 }


}
```

Comment: btw, you sure a player's BA is computed from all the other players' cumulative stats (ref. line `sum += ...` in `getData`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust `showData` function to use `std::ofstream` indstead of `std::cout`.

```
bool writeData(Baseball stats[], int players, std::string const& filePath)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(filePath);

    if(!ofs.is_open())
        return false; // failed to open stream

    ofs << endl << endl;
    ofs << "lets see how this aquasock stats stack up!\n\n";


    ofs << "First Name" << setw(14) << "Last Name" << setw(6) << "AB" << setw(6) << "1B" << setw(6) << "2B";
    ofs << setw(6) << "3B" << setw(6) << "HR" << setw(6) << "BB" << setw(6) << "BA" << setw(6) << "SA";
    ofs << setw(6) << "OBA" << "\n";


    ofs << "----------" << setw(14) << "---------" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--";
    ofs << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--" << setw(6) << "--";
    ofs << setw(6) << "---" << "\n";


    for(int i = 0; i < players; ++i)
    {
        ofs << stats[i].FirstName
             << setw(15) << stats[i].LastName
             << setw(8) << stats[i].AB
             << setw(8) << stats[i].singles
             << setw(8) << stats[i].doubles
             << setw(8) << stats[i].triples
             << setw(8) << stats[i].HR
             << setw(8) << stats[i].walks
             << setw(8) << stats[i].BA
             << setw(8) << stats[i].SA
             << setw(8) << stats[i].OBA
             << endl;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or to reuse the code, you could use function template, or even better, pass your stream into the function (`std::ostream` is base class of `std::ofstream` and `std::cout` is `std::ostream` itself)

```
void writeData(Baseball stats[], int players, std::ostream &os);
```

And change `cout`s to `os`s. You can then use it to write to console:

```
writeData(stats, players, std::cout);
```

Or file:

```
std::ofstream ofs(filePath);

if(!ofs.is_open())
{
    // error
}

writeData(stats, players, ofs);
```

I hope this solves your doubts.

Comment: This has been super helpful and i cant thank you enough.   Is it really that simple to store the data from the code?  no wonder i had it wrong, I was in the impression that each line had to have  ofstream modifier.  thank you again for your help

Comment: for some weird reason the code wont compile now,codebloc is telling me that in my int main there is no matching function.

Comment: @mcmoroge LogicStuff has correctly answered your question. The appropriate
response is to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You have a new problem now, which
is clearly caused by a coding error on your part. If you can't fix it by your own best efforts feel free to ask another question. Accepting correct answers boosts your chances of getting answers to your further questions.

Comment: @mcmoroge I bet you forgot to change/add forward declaration of the `writeData` or didn't change `showData(stats, players);` if you've overwrited/removed it.

Comment: @MikeKinghan i see what you mean and thank you for letting me know, I just get so overwhelmed with coding that i think all the problems are related.

Comment: @LogicStuff thank you for your help and you are correct, I did forget to change the showdata(stats, players)  i was just so excited to finally move forward in the learning process of fstream.   I am glad there is a website to help us lost souls of coding

Comment: @mcmoroge You're welcome. I hope you've used `void writeData(Baseball stats[], int players, std::ostream &os);`, not the first version. You can also do this with `getData` and read your data back from the file.